# Jenkins multi-branch pipeline and specifying upstream projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We currently generate a lot of Jenkins jobs on a per Git branch basis using Jenkins job DSL; the multi-branch pipeline plugin looks like an interesting way to potentially get first-class job generation support using Jenkinsfiles and reduce the amount of Job DSL we maintain.

For example we have *libwidget-server* and *widget-server* develop branch projects. When the libwidget-server build finishes then the widget-server job is triggered (for the develop branch). This applies to other branches too.

This makes use of the `Build after other projects are built` to trigger upon completion of an upstream build (e.g. libwidget-server causes widget-server to be built).

It seems that the multi-branch pipeline plugin lacks the `Build after other projects are built` setting - how would we accomplish the above in the multi-branch pipeline build?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should add the branch name to your upstream job (assuming you are using a multi-branch pipeline for the upstream job too).

Suppose you have a folder with two jobs, both multi-branch pipeline jobs: `jobA` and `jobB`; `jobB` should trigger after `jobA`'s `master`.

You can add this code snippet to `jobB`'s Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([
  pipelineTriggers([
    upstream(
      threshold: 'SUCCESS',
      upstreamProjects: '../jobA/master'
    )
  ])
])
```

(Mind that any branch of `jobB` here will trigger after `jobA`'s master!)

Comment: The upstreams in our case are not multi-branch pipelines but I'll do some tests with that. I also still need to look at @cscutcher's suggestion above.

Comment: It works perfectly well for multibranch jobs, but seems to be unsupported for bitbucket branch source plug-in.

Comment: You can refer to other jobs from within multibranch job using absolute or relative paths `"/t/multibranch-job/master, ../multibranch-job/master, test, feature%252Ftest"`

Comment: When i try this method I am getting `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticField hudson.model.Result UNSTABLE` exception. Is there a way around it? Or should I ask the admin to whitelist the API (Which is tedious)?

Comment: @luka5z how does that look?

properties([
  pipelineTriggers([
    upstream(
      threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS,
      upstreamProjects: '"/t/multibranch-job/master, ../multibranch-job/master, test, feature%252Ftest"
    )
  ])
])

Comment: @Codebender a bit late, but I believe the updated answer should solve your exception?

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently trying to get this to work for our deployment.
The closest I've got is adding the following to the downstream Jenkinsfile;

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        triggers: [
            [
                $class: 'jenkins.triggers.ReverseBuildTrigger',
                upstreamProjects: "some_project", result: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
            ]
        ]
    ]),
])
```

That at least gets Jenkins to acknowledge that it should be triggering when
'some_project' get's built i.e it appears in the "View Configuration" page.

However so far builds of 'some_project' still don't trigger the downstream
project as expected.

That being said maybe you'll have more luck.
Let me know if it works for you.

(Someone else has asked a similar question here -> [Jenkins: Trigger Multi-branch pipeline on upstream change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825103/jenkins-trigger-multi-branch-pipeline-on-upstream-change) )

Comment: This worked for me when I replaced `result:` with `threshold:`. I also specified a matching branch of a multi-branch pipeline with `"some_project/" + env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll("/", "%2F")`

Comment: @cscutcher, @Ross Lagerwall, using declarative `triggers { upstream() }` is not working for me to chain 2 multibranch pipeline jobs, using Jenkins 2.249.2, Pipeline: Multibranch v2.22, Pipeline v2.6, Pipeline: Job v2.4. I read somewhere that the upstream job needs to be specified as a "path", as @Jo Vandeginste suggests above, but it's not working for me either as a job name ("common_folder/mb_project/branch") or path ("../../other_mb_project/branch")...