# Jenkins Pipeline: Enable timestamps in build log console

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How can I display build timestamps for each line of a multi-branch pipeline project? Is it a supported feature? If yes, does it need to be enabled in the `Jenkinsfile` or is there a GUI option?

Comment: `options { timestamps() }` below the `agent` should work. I forget where I learned it, but you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956598/how-to-set-job-properties-for-jobs-within-a-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline-projec/42961160#42961160). I don't know how to tell what things are supported inside `options` but `timestamps()` is. Pretty sure you need this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Timestamper.

Comment: @Quantic Can I use `options` in a scripted pipeline?

Comment: Oh, I don't know. I use declarative with a couple `script {}` sections. I'm not having any luck figuring it out with their docs either.

Comment: That link isn't working. https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For scripted pipeline just wrap your script in `timestamps { }`
Eg.

```
timestamps {
  // do your job
}
```

**Note:** You must have the timestamper plugin installed:  [wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Timestamper](http://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Timestamper)

Comment: I just noticed that (at least in our setup) you can configure this globally: check the "Enabled for all Pipeline builds" in the "Timestamper" section in Jenkins configuration

Comment: The option mentioned by @roomsg can be found under `<jenkins_url>/configure`

Comment: That link isn't working. How about https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/

Answer (score 122):

Adding options to the declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options { timestamps () }
  // stages and rest of pipeline.
}
```

Credit goes to the comment above [Jenkins Pipeline: Enable timestamps in build log console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039924/jenkins-pipeline-enable-timestamps-in-build-log-console#comment81033213_47039924)

Comment: I actually find this more useful than just timestamping specific code blocks.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo yeah its really useful only for declarative pipelines, not for scripted pipelines

Comment: Doesn't work for me:

`WorkflowScript: 3: Invalid option type "timestamps". Valid option types [ansiColor, buildDiscarder,...]`

Comment: @ChrisWolf, late to the party you are probably missing the Timestamper plugin

Comment: what format would be for elapsed time?

Comment: @wiredniko - thanks, but unfortunately forced to use a version of Jenkins too old for the `Timestamper` plugin. :(

Comment: i no longer see this plugin Timestamper

Answer (score 6):

I'm wondering why [roomsg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039924/jenkins-pipeline-enable-timestamps-in-build-log-console#comment100478175_47387101) on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387101) didn't become an answer.

> I just noticed that (at least in our setup) you can configure this
> globally: check the "Enabled for all Pipeline builds" in the
> "Timestamper" section in Jenkins configuration

I think this is the best answer for the question. So, in case you have access as admin, you can set it for all pipeline jobs through GUI.

Comment: Completely agree. It's a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

To enable Timestamper globally (all builds):

- Go to the Jenkins configuration
- Go to the "Timestamper" configration

-> Select the "Enabled for all Pipeline builds" checkbox.