# Disable Jenkins pipeline log timestamp

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the Jenkins pipeline, I am getting console logs  as below.

```
19:09:36  -----------------------
19:09:36  my echo statements 
19:09:36  -----------------------
```

I'd want all the information in the console logs  in this pipeline execution to be without timestamps.

```
  -----------------------
  my echo statements 
  -----------------------
```

When i checked, it was recommended that the below option be used in the pipeline, however this did not help. Are there any other ways by which these logs can be disabled?

```
options {
   timestamps {
       skipPrintingTimestamps()
   }
}
```

Comment: When did you check? What is it? Can you reference the recommendation? And which plugin are you using for the timestamp functionality? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47039924/367456

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem is to unchecked from the Configure section of the Jenkins. *"Enabled for all Pipeline builds"* This is coming from the time stamper plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/

[image]